# How to retrieve value from cxf RAW message using xpath

Tags: xpath, soap, cxf

Below is my code snippet for Camel Context in Spring DSL. I can retrieve 
value from PAYLOAD message but not able to retrieve using RAW. Is there any way we can retrieve value from RAW message which is a SOAP request XML?

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint address="/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/" endpointName="vi:nameService" id="SOAPInput"
  serviceName="vi:nameService" wsdlURL="wsdl/name.wsdl" xmlns:vi="http://services.visa.com/xx/xx/xx/xxx">
    <camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"> 
        <from id="Listener" uri="cxf:bean:SOAPInput?dataFormat=RAW"/>
        <setProperty id="setName" propertyName="name">
            <xpath resultType="java.lang.String" trim="false">/*/*/*/v1:getname/name/text()</xpath>
        </setProperty>
```